# custom string format according to culture (reporting services)

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I am working on a issue related with hard code value for the format property in some reports.
No I am trying create custom format according to the culture code of my customers.
The problem with my code is what my new format (for es-CL and en-US cultures) are not working, wich should be the correct mask if for en-US the thousan separator is , and . for es-Cl?
Thank you

```
Public Shared Function GetTextMortNumberFormat(culture) As String
Select Case culture 
    Case "nb-NO"
        Return "# ### ###;-# ### ###;''"
    Case "es-CL"
        Return "#.###.###;-#.###.###;''"
    Case "en-US"
        Return "#,###,###;-#,###,###;''"
    Case Else           
        Return "# ### ###;-# ### ###;''"
End Select      
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use the user's internationalization settings. For the Language property of the report itself, use:

```
=User!Language
```

Now you can use the following formats which will use the user's regional language settings to format numbers appropriately:

- N2 = number with 2 decimal places
- N0 = number with no decimal places
- P0 = percent with no decimal places
- d = short date format

You can see other [format strings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Hello Chris Latta,
I could set the language property of the rdl file using something like language=Parameters!language.Value  or language=User!Language
, but what about when the value is 0 and i want show a space (' '). 

I could use a expression like that may be..
=IIF(Code.IsZeroOrEmpty(Fields!MyField.Value)," ",Fields!MyFields.Value)..

Answer (score 0):

The comma will always try to substitute in the locale's thousands separator, and the period will anchor to the decimal position and substitute the locale's decimal separator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

You can hard code in a locale by using just a little .net: [format number in ssrs report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388398/format-number-in-ssrs-report/5398265#5398265)